# Combining attributes of point data within buffer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, fields-attributes, spatial-query, parcel

I have city data broken down into intersections and roads.  Around each intersection, I have created a buffer.  I also have parcel data, including the attribute "gross tax 2015" for each parcel.  I would like to assign each parcel intersecting a buffer to that intersection- and then analyze the total tax information for each intersection (there is more than one parcel in each buffer).  I have been able to create the buffer, and can visually see the parcels in each buffer, but can't seem to get an attribute table that shows to which intersection each parcel is assigned.  Furthermore, a parcel may reside in more than one buffer.  Is there any way to get the percent area of each parcel in each buffer?

I am using QGIS 2.8.6

Comment: The answer to most "Is there any way..." questions is likely to be "Probably -- What software are you using?"  Please always include the GIS software in use within the body of your question.

Comment: My advice for something like this would be to learn PostGIS using this problem... from a SQL spatial point of view, you'll be first creating the buffers using ST_Buffer, then intersecting the parcels to the buffers, then grabbing the intersection ID and assigning it to the intersecting parcels - I'd turn that into 1 new table. Then you can write a query that will SUM the 'gross tax' for each parcel and GROUP BY the intersectionID... then if you'd like, you can join the geometry of the intersections back to the SUM table (join on INTERSECTION ID), then map the SUM'd 'gross tax' values in QGIS!