# Select by Location > Assign value from a different layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity, arcgis-10.5, select-by-location

Is it possible to identify, for example, a data point that is within ‘X’ distance of a Well, and then “create a field” that would assign the Well ID Value to that data point?

Ideally, this would need to be done for multiple wells (over 100), and for multiple data points, simultaneously.

For example, NPDES permits that are within 800’ of a well.

- 1 permit is found within 800’ of well 1002, and would therefore be assigned to this well ID
- 3 permits are found with 800’ of well 637, so each one of these permit would be assigned with well ID 637

ATTRIBUTE TABLE EXAMPLE:

NEW FIELD
NPDES Permit#   Well w/in 800’

10232               1002

76542                637

6798245              637

4325                 637
ETC…

The underlying goal is to identify wells that are most susceptible to contamination. As such, I need a way to multiple contamination points to individual wells. So, from the example above, well 1002 would essentially get 1 point, while well 637 would get 3.

Is there another (better) way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a buffer based on your point layer, in QGIS the procedure is as follows:  https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Buffer_with_QGIS

Then you can count points in polygon: [Count points within each buffer QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220903/count-points-within-each-buffer-qgis)